# Minimising jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you recommend on minimizing this code? As you can see there is a lot of repeating code.

Im sure many of you may have written code as i have below. But im hoping that there is a way to shorten the amount of code needed.

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
if(index >= 2 && index <= 5)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market-active.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 6 && index <= 10)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote-active.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 11 && index <= 16)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order-active.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 17 && index <= 21)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in-active.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 22)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking-active.png"  ); 
}
```

EDIT:

The images are a menu bar across the bottom of the page. Sort of like a chapter of a book. One button will show as activated (a different image) when you are in that section and the others will not. Also i am using jQuery cycle.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what problem you're trying to solve. There may be an alternative way to approach it that would be simpler :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, ive added some more information in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would rewrite this to use CSS classes and background images instead. Something like this:

```css
.menu-item { /* base settings for all menu items */ }

.menu-item.market {
    background-image: url('images/menu-market.png');
}
.menu-item.market.active {
    background-image: url('images/menu-market-active.png');
}

.menu-item.quote {
    background-image: url('images/menu-quote.png');
}
.menu-item.quote.active {
    background-image: url('images/menu-quote-active.png');
}

/* Same for 'order', 'in' and 'taking' */
```

Now all you have to do in JavaScript is something like this (once):

```js
$(".menu-item-2").addClass('menu-item market');
$(".menu-item-3").addClass('menu-item quote');
$(".menu-item-4").addClass('menu-item order');
$(".menu-item-5").addClass('menu-item in');
$(".menu-item-6").addClass('menu-item taking');
```

And this (when `index` changes):

```
$('.menu-item').removeClass('active');

if(index >= 2 && index <= 5) {
    $('.menu-item.market').addClass('active');
} else if (index >= 6 && index <= 10) {
    $('.menu-item.quote').addClass('active');
} else if (index >= 11 && index <= 16) {
    $('.menu-item.order').addClass('active');
} else if (index >= 17 && index <= 21) {
    $('.menu-item.in').addClass('active');
} else if (index >= 22) {
    $('.menu-item.taking').addClass('active');
}
```

Taking this approach has two main advantages:

- Separation of logic and presentation. By adding classes you describe *what it is*, not *what it should look like*. This makes it easy to go back and, e.g., change an icon.
- Instead of using `.menu-item-2`, `.menu-item-3`, et cetera, you could use the `menu-item` class in HTML (if it can be changed) and iterate over `$(.menu-item)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But you can change: `$(".menu-item-2").addClass('menu-item').addClass('market');` to `$(".menu-item-2").addClass('menu-item market');`

Comment: I have decided to use this answer as it does seperate logic and presentation. Which is always a good thing!

Comment: @AndreasAL: Thanks! You're right and I updated the answer. I didn't RTFM while writing this up and I never added more than one class before. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple jQuery plugin to do it (this will only work for the **first matched element**):

```
$.fn.activate = function () {
   var firstElement = this[0],
       $img,
       src;       

   // Deactivate all the other ones
   $("img").each(function () { // <-- customise this selector to match all images
        $img = $(this);
        src = $img.attr("src"); 
        if (src.indexOf("-active") > -1) {
            $img.attr("src", src.replace("-active", ""));
        }        
    });

   // Activate this one
   firstElement.attr("src", firstElement.attr("src").replace(".png", "-active.png"));  
};
```

And apply the plugin like this:

```
if(index >= 2 && index <= 5) {
    $(".menu-item-2 img").activate();
} else if (index >= 6 && index <= 10) {
    $(".menu-item-3 img").activate();
} else if (index >= 11 && index <= 16) {
    $(".menu-item-4 img").activate();
} else if (index >= 17 && index <= 21) {
    $(".menu-item-5 img").activate();
} else if (index >= 22) {
    $(".menu-item-6 img").activate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little obfuscated, but should get the job done:

```
var current = 0, src, images = ['','','market','quote','order','in','taking'],
    active = [0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6];

if(active[index]) { current = active[index]; }
else if(index > active.length) { current = 6; }

for(var i=2; i<7; i++) {
    src = "images/menu-" + images[i];
    if(i == current) { src += "-active"; }
    src += ".png";
    $(".menu-item-" + i + " img").attr("src", src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this:

```
$(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market.png"  );
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in.png"  ); 
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking.png"  );

if(index >= 2 && index <= 5)
{
    $(".menu-item-2 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-market-active.png"  );
}
if(index >= 6 && index <= 10)
{
    $(".menu-item-3 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-quote-active.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 11 && index <= 16)
{
    $(".menu-item-4 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-order-active.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 17 && index <= 21)
{
    $(".menu-item-5 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-in-active.png"  ); 
}
if(index >= 22)
{
    $(".menu-item-6 img").attr( "src" , "images/menu-taking-active.png"  ); 
}
```

Comment: I will also need to unactivate one as well. For example when index changes from 5-6 then 2 would be activated instead of just the one needed.

Comment: Put it inside a function and call it every time the index changes, it will reset all active and select the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following expression will give you the number of the menu item which needs to be use the active image

```
Math.floor((index-2)/5+2);
```

Then you can simplify the rest of the code to.

```
$(".menu-item-2 img").attr("src", "images/menu-market.png");
$(".menu-item-3 img").attr("src", "images/menu-quote.png"); 
$(".menu-item-4 img").attr("src", "images/menu-order.png"); 
$(".menu-item-5 img").attr("src", "images/menu-in.png"); 
$(".menu-item-6 img").attr("src", "images/menu-taking.png");

var active = Math.floor((index-2)/5+2), $active_menu = $(".menu-item-"+active+" img");

$active_menu.attr("src", $active_menu.attr("src").replace(".png", "-active.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Add an `id="i"` to all of your menu items, set the css class attribute to equaly `class="menu-item"`

**2:**

```
$('.menu-item').click(function () {
    $('.menu-item').each(function(){
        /* Unselected picture */
        $(this img).attr('src', 'images/menu-' + $(this).attr('id') + '_unselected.png');
    });
    /* selected picture */
    $(this img).attr('src', 'images/menu-' + $(this).attr('id') + '_selected.png');
});
```